# Can I safely disable HTTP methods DELETE and OPTIONS?

Tags: security, iis

A recent security audit recommended that I disable the HTTP methods DELETE and OPTIONS.
I am not opposed to doing this, but have been unable to find any documentation indicating that I can do so safely, without degrading functionality in the CMS.

Does Sitecore need/use the DELETE and/or OPTIONS HTTP methods?
Is there documentation to support one way or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the question to Sitecore support, who came back with three points on this (paraphrasing):

- 'Pure' Sitecore uses only POST and GET
- Modules may use other verbs, particularly if communicating with a 3rd party (Ex: Social Connected, item WebAPI, WebDAV)
- Because of the use in modules, **disabling the verbs is not recommended** (emphasis mine)

My takeaway; Your own mileage may vary depending on the modules you need, but tread lightly if your instance is anything more than basic.

Answer (score 1):

I have the `options` disabled on a live website and that is running fine. So that should work.

Not sure about the `delete` method however. Didn't test that one yet. It might be used in an api, but maybe someone else can confirm that.